# Proof of an implications involving inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization, contest-math

Suppose $$\lambda_{1} = \frac{1}{2} (x^2z - \sqrt{4wy^2 + x^4z^2}) , \lambda_2 =\frac{1}{2} (x^2z + \sqrt{4wy^2 + x^4z^2})$$ $$\lambda_3 = \frac{1}{2} (w^2 + y+xz^2 - \sqrt{-4w^2y + (-w^2-y-xz^2)^2}) $$
$$\lambda_4 = \frac{1}{2} (w^2 + y+xz^2 + \sqrt{-4w^2y + (-w^2-y-xz^2)^2})$$

$S=\{(x,y,z,w)| |\lambda_1|<1, |\lambda_2|<1, |\lambda_3|<1, |\lambda_4|<1 \}$

Now after trying several examples, I have a conjecture in mind that for all elements of set $S$,
$$1+w+x+wy+xz-yz<0$$ AND $1-wx + y + wy+z+xz < 0$ cannot happen.

Any ideas of a proof?
Note $x,y,z,w \in \Bbb{R}$

Comment: Is the whole thing your conjecture? Including the expressions of $\lambda_{1,2,3,4}$?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I am thinking of a proof as to why such implication holds

Comment: Check: $x = 1/2, y = -5/3, z = -2, w = 0$.